# Need S3 policy to allow authenticated google users

Tags: amazon-s3, policy

I am new to AWS/S3. Earlier I am using Google Cloud. I have gone through some forums, posts, but I am not able to find similar to my requirement so I am writing this post here.

First I would like to explain my requirement and how I used to practice in Google Cloud and in return I am expecting someone could help me how to do the same requirement in AWS/S3.

In Google cloud I used to save images in Storage Buckets. So every image has its own URL. For say the url is: **"https://console.developers.google.com/m/cloudstorage/b/my-bucket/o/my-image.pdf"**. When ever user try to open this URL in browser, it will redirect to google accounts page, after User logged in using google account, the image will be displayed in browser.

Now, in AWS-S3, I have created one bucket and uploaded images in it, the URL for that image is **"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket3162017/cahngetheworld.jpg"**. So, what kind of policy do I need to attach to the BUcket, if I want to tell user to login through Google Account.

I want to allow only google accounts into my s3 bucket instead making it public to everyone. Literally I am try to add one more policy similar to "All Autheticated AWS User" as "All Authenticated Google Users". Help me if anybody has any thoughts about it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible at S3 policy level. You'd want to look further into AWS IAM, specifically federated identity providers.

Comment: *Literally I am try to add one more policy similar to "All Autheticated AWS User" as "All Authenticated Google Users".*  Literally, there is no such option.  S3 does not have a native concept of an authenticated web browser user.  That isn't how S3's authentication model works.

Comment: Hi Jingx/Michael, Thanks for your comments. Can you suggest me how can I proceed with User Federation at IAM level. As I have seen a policy {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "accounts.google.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "accounts.google.com:aud": "GoogleAppIdHere.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}